# socket.io not emit to rooms outside the context of Socket.IO processes with io.adapter(redis)

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

I'm trying to emit events from outside the context of Socket.IO processes into specific room.

WORKING EXAMPLE of `io.emit` without specifying `roomId`:

```
 // client side
socket.emit('join-chat-room');
socket.on('client-side-channel', data => {
  console.log('Got message:', data);
});


// server side set redis adapter
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
const redisUrl = env.REDIS_URL;
const pubClient = redis.createClient(redisUrl);
const subClient = redis.createClient(redisUrl);

const adapter = redisAdapter({ pubClient, subClient });
adapter.prototype.on('error', function (err) {
  log.error(`adapter error: ${err}`);
});

io.adapter(adapter);
```

WORKING: io.to(...).emit(...) in context of socket:

```
socket.on('join-chat-room', async () => {
  await socket.join('chat-room');
  io.to('chat-room').emit('client-side-channel', 'chat-data1');
});
```

NOT-WORKING: io.to(...).emit(...) from outside the context of Socket.IO processes:

```
io.to('chat-room').emit('client-side-channel', 'chat-data2');
```

but this works from outside the context of Socket.IO processes:

```
io.emit('client-side-channel', 'chat-data2');
```

Comment: Are you executing `io.to('chat-room').emit('client-side-channel', 'chat-data2');` at a time when that room doesn't yet exist?  Or nobody has yet connected?  Have you stepped into that call in the debugger and watched what it does so you can see why it isn't sending? This is all very debuggable on your part.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to debug using io.sockets.adapter.rooms

Comment: Well, I meant that you could just step into your call to `io.to('chat-room').emit('client-side-channel', 'chat-data2');` and watch line by line what it does and see why it doesn't send to anyone.